# merging uilabel and uiimageview

Tags: ios, merge, uiimageview, uilabel

I picked an image from the photo album and put it in an `UIImageView` called imageView
I then added some text over the image using `UITextView` as source of input and a `UILabel` on top of the uiimageview to display the text.

So far so good.

Now I'm trying to merge the label and the imageview in order to do other stuff with that but I 'm not getting it to work. I have tried some solutions given to similar questions but they didn't work for me.

I tried this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0); //retina res
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[_displaylabel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

it tells me that Received type "`CAlayer` for instance message is a forward declaration".

any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you've added the QuartzCore framework and imported it with #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>?  I don't have a specific answer to your question, but this should at least fix the "CAlayer for instance message is a forward declaration" error.

Comment: it helped to remove the errors but it's not merging the views :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0); //retina res
[self.imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Make sure that the UILabel is a subview of your UIImageView, so that rendering the layer will include all sublayers (the UILabel included). It seems like you forgot to include UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); too, which may have been the issue

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get it to work. there are no errors displayed. If i try to save the image then it get saved but without the text in the uilabel. I'm getting frustrated, this should be easy.

Comment: Hm, well here's a small example project I made that should do what I think you're trying to accomplish. Look at the ViewDidLoad method inside of ViewController.m

https://github.com/justinrushing/imageview_with_text

Comment: hey Justin, thanks for your help but this solution is only saving the imageview without the label :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
 UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height)];
    [tempView addSubview:imgView];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tempView.frame.size.width/2, 0, 200, tempView.frame.size.height/2)];
[label setText:@"Hello... You there"];
[label setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[tempView addSubview:label];


 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempView.bounds.size);
    [tempView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```