# while applying overlay images to image which is taken from camera at that time app will terminates in ios

Tags: ios

taking an image either from gallery or camera.which is converts into pencil sketch when we applying overlays to image.At this time my app is crashing due to memory leak.getting image from gallery is fine .but taking image from camera and apply overlay images to pencil sketch image at this case only app terminates .please anybody help me
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` instead of `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` you will solve this type of memory leaks. Please refer [this](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/) tutorial for your reference.

```
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
```

Comment: hi.i am new to iOS .what i have done is getting image from camera or gallery..now i want to enter text where
 ever i want in different colors and different styles,different sizes on image.i searched but not getting proper answer..please anybody help me to do this

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030240/merging-uilabel-and-uiimageview/27479436#27479436) is the code for Merge label in to the image. Try this one. If you have any queries give your mail id I will send this sample.

Comment: after getting image from gallery or camera i want to add text in anywhere using gestures i want to move text ..text can be in different styles of fonts,different colors ..dont know how to do this please help me

Comment: if we use label means only we add the text in that place only..right..but my requirement is user can  add the the text anywhere on image ..that text should move ..i have tried but not getting proper answer ..

Comment: Please try [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Rp_LIFCktOSWFyVjBmNnlJTUhXeUh4RC1UajJqOGJuN2o4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: how can i apply the different fonts to text on image when we select perticular text to perticular  font

Comment: please anybody help me to do this

Comment: how to apply different font styles to text on image

Comment: how to add zoom to text on image?

Comment: First you get the particular label using tag and if you choose the colour, just apply that colour to text label.textColor=selectedColor; For different font and size  [label.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12 ]]